# How would i pull the lower value in my table using my case statement

Tags: sql

i have used a `CASE` expression to split down the table and give it the headings needed to import, which works great, `Query` below.

The problem i am now facing is in my `Wordpress DB` i have found that i have duplicates of the same `meta_key` which are `_price` and `_regular_price` as you can see below this will only pull  one of them, and you guessed it, its the wrong one is there a way i can pull both lots of `_price` and `_regular_price`

```
select post_id,
max(case when meta_key = '_sku' then meta_value end) _sku,
max(case when post_id NOT LIKE 'NULL' then post_id end) post_id,
max(case when meta_key = '_regular_price' then meta_id end) _regular_price_1,
max(case when meta_key = '_price' then meta_id end) _price_1
from wp_postmeta
group by post_id;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_postmeta` (
`meta_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`post_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `wp_postmeta`
--

INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES

(10429 , 2736,'_sku','RDPR00026'),
(10430 , 2736, '_regular_price', '1.87'),
(10447, 2736, '_price', '1.87'),
(383416,2736,'_regular_price','1.75'),
(383420,2736,'_price', '1.75'),
```

[DB-Fiddle Of Where i have got to](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p4XhyyCFP5uzohvc9ohShH/0)

any help would be much appreciated

i am hoping to achieve

[image]

Comment: So... what would the result look like, for example, for the post_id `2736`? Do you want two sets of rows for it? Please add it to the question.

Comment: As a side note: it's a CASE _expression_ not a statement.

Comment: thank you for the heads up @a_horse_with_no_name being new to `sql` is a understatement any help and advice is great